# more command displays how many lines at a time?

Tags: more

When we use the more command it usually print the screensize of text, so my question is the maximum number of lines a more command usually prints??? I mean by default how many lines it can accommodate at a time on the screen? I want to know the exact line number value??

Answer (score 3):

As you seem to know, it prints the number of lines available on the screen less one for the `more` indicator at the bottom of the screen.

To find out how many lines are available on a specific terminal window, simply look at the first line of `stty -a` showing the number of rows.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your answer.

Comment: What are you not getting?  Did you look at `stty -a`?

Comment: I don't know how to use this "stty -a"

Comment: Type that in a shell.  I suppose you must know how to open a shell since you ask about the `more` command.

Comment: I used this it is returning how many rows are there according to screensize,but I'm unable to find how many rows are ther? when we use the more command?

Comment: speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;

Comment: When I given that stty -a It return this portion info: speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0; here I can see but I want to know exactly the more command will return

Comment: I know how to open the shell & how to give the commands, I hope you might understood with my above responses thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: It will show 23 lines of the file plus the `more` line at the bottom, as I answered.